# Should community wiki posts give +2 for suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, community-wiki

I just noticed that when an user with less than 100 rep suggests an edit on a community wiki post that gets approved, he gets +2 rep, just as for a suggested edit on a normal post.

However, I don't think that is fair. Nobody gets any rep for community wiki posts, so I think that the +2 is also misplaced.

On the other hand, I do not know whether we really should want to deprive some user with less than 100 rep of a little rep bonus.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Huh. I'm shocked that nobody <s>noticed</s>  um <s>posted to meta</s>  okay, posted-to-meta-and-I-saw-it about this before.

That does feel like a broken situation at first glance. Here I think it helps to go back to the original reasons for both systems in the first place.

Community Wiki was originally envisioned as a feature for great posts that had substantial contributions from many users, such that it wouldn't be fair for rep from that post to go to any one user (specifically, the original author). Granted, it pretty much was never used that way since day one. Instead, it has been pressed into service for polls and wherever people have wanted a quick rep denial mechanism... not the greatest situations. In truth, the CW status has already all but been phased out.

Suggested edit rep, meanwhile, was introduced as the "carrot" part of a way to gently bring newer users into the editing part of the SE model. Certainly, teaching people about editing is still something to be encouraged.

Given that CW has always been a sort-of-mess that never functioned as intended, and that the kind of user who's likely to be earning suggested edit rep (i.e. new users) is unlikely to be aware of the history of already-rare CW content type, I'd say leave the +2s in these edge cases intact.

Comment: I tend to agree. Like I explained in the question, theoretically it would be better to not have the +2, but having the +2 is just more practical. Also, if the +2 would be removed, we might get people complaining about where their +2 is.

Comment: It's also an incredibly low amount of reputation they could ever earn from suggesting edits to community wiki posts, since they'll stop suggesting on them once they hit the 100 reputation mark. Dev effort and extra intricacies to prevent such a tiny amount isn't even worth it.