# Why is no reputation gained for approved edits on Community Wiki questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, community-wiki

I haven't found any Q/A on meta about this, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

I recently made an edit to a Software Engineering.SE Community Wiki answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/157175/3), which was approved. I received the "Excavator" badge today as a result, but no (+2) reputation.

Of course I'm not upset about it, but I'm a bit confused as to why reputation isn't given for CW approved edits. In my eyes, the +2 reputation is a small way to incentivize good edits to all Q/A; so, **why is no reputation gained from CW edits when the goal - to improve Q/A quality - is the same**?

I'm just curious as to the rationale; I'm not asking for any change in the system regarding rep for CWs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you only get +2 reputation after it is *approved* by other members of the community. This is true for normal edits (for which you don't gain any reputation after reaching 2,000 reputation), for tag wiki edits (for which the threshold is 20,000), and for Community Wiki edits as well (for which the bar is set at 100 reputation). If you have *less than 100 reputation* and edit a Community Wiki, it's still going to be reviewed and you gain reputation when the edit is approved.

Answer (score 8):

Your edit wasn't approved as it didn't need to be. As stated in [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/307988) the reputation needed to unilaterally edit a community wiki post is 100, rather than the 2000 for normal posts. You have 1k+ on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) so can edit community wiki posts without the need for peer review.

Although it doesn't explicitly mention t in the FAQ, as you can see from [Should community wiki posts give +2 for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276423/307988) you do gain the regular +2 from approved edits to community wiki posts.